# Create stored procedure with given sql statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to creating stored procedures and there is a situation where we can't touch the database directly and everyone has to write a stored procedure such that, stored procedure is completely reproducible across various environments.

```
/**
The following steps are needed for making manufacturing cert to work with service

--insert a "manufacturing_system" entry in the table
insert into  [Auth].[Principals] (PrincipalTypeID, Name, IsEnabled) 
values (5, 'manufacturing_system', 1)

--SELECT ID FROM [DVMTO2APP].[Auth].[Principals] where Name = 'manufacturing_system'
--5

--used for making 'HELLO' and 'AUTHENTICATE' part of authentication stored procedure work

--select URI from [DVMTO2APP].[Auth].Permissions where URI like '%'
--1
Insert into [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions] (PrincipalID, PermissionID, isAllowed) 
values (5, 1, 1)

-- used for Authorizing publish and subscribe on heartbeat stream, 
--select ID from [DVMTO2APP].[Auth].Permissions where URI like '%heartbeat%'
--43,44

Insert into [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions] (PrincipalID, PermissionID, isAllowed) 
values (5, 43, 1)
Insert into [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions] (PrincipalID, PermissionID, isAllowed) 
values (5, 44, 1)

-- used for Authorizing register and call action for install_cert RPC,
--select ID from [DVMTO2APP].[Auth].Permissions where URI like '%install_%'
--29,30
Insert into [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions] (PrincipalID, PermissionID, isAllowed)  
values (5, 29, 1)
Insert into [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions] (PrincipalID, PermissionID, isAllowed) 
values (5, 30, 1)

**/
```

Comment: Do you have insert access for the data table? What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: Please tag your `RDBMS`

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: When you say you have to do everything through stored-procedures - does that include every single `SELECT` query? What if you need to use an ORM in your application code? Can you have a sproc that accepts a single string parameter that's executed as raw SQL? If you have to do this for security or compliance rules then it sounds like you have a DBA (or CTO) who rules through cargo-cult practices instead of doing things properly, in which case you have my sympathy (i.e. there are MUCH better ways of securing a database than weird rules like this).

Comment: we are not able to use ORM's as that's how authentication logic for applications is structured as it's "recommended" way of doing things. as far as using ORM we can't just start using it as then we will have to revamp lot more things.